# C#,Asp.net: How to upload file from local machine to other machine in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a website using asp.net.I wondered how to upload file from my machine to other machine by IPaddress using fileUpload.thanks

**Html**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ToolTip="Select Only Excel File" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUploadClick" Text="Upload" />
</form>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("admin", "jetnexus");
        Uri addy = new Uri(@"\\192.168.2.19\jetnexus\etc\");
        client.Credentials = nc;
        byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(addy, FileUpload1.FileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File upload works on client. So only client can upload the file.
So If you want to upload from any machine you application must be accessable to that machine.
And you can map the network drive to upload any file using file upload.

I think you Can use like this

```
  Stream stream = client.OpenRead(addy);
  String request = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

and then save it using file stream.

Comment: I edit my description.It didn't work.May you point it for me.Thanks

Comment: What should we use with "request" varialbe?

Comment: It always show "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."